# How can I effectively route Stylus RMX channels to individual MIDI tracks in Ableton Live?

Tags: midi, software, ableton-live, production

I'm currently facing challenges with routing separate Stylus RMX channels to individual MIDI tracks in Ableton Live in a well-organized manner. While I've followed tutorials to create a functional drum beat, I lack confidence in the setup and would appreciate a better understanding before proceeding with my composition.

I'm uncertain whether the routing method is specific to Stylus or if it pertains to multitimbral plug-ins in general, governed by fundamental mapping and routing techniques. As someone new to programming drums in this particular way, I might be overlooking a basic aspect.

To date, I've referred to various guides, including those linked below. Despite consulting these resources and reaching out to Spectrasonics support, I still find myself struggling to grasp the logic behind the routing.
If anyone could assist me in untangling my routing setup and point me in the right direction, I would be so grateful.

The following are the screenshots from my current session: [image: Ableton Live 11]

[image: Stylus RMX]

-286642

Resources:

[Stylus RMX Video Tutorials: "Using Separate Outputs"](https://vimeo.com/17337053);

[Gearspace.com Post: "Stylus RMX Multiple Outs?"](https://gearspace.com/board/music-computers/122386-stylus-rmx-multiple-outs.html);

[Youtube: "Spectrasonics Stylus RMX in Ableton 10 Multiple Outs"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ornrv9CtI_U);

[Ableton Reference Manual: 15.5.2.6 Using Multi-Timbral Plug-In Instruments](https://www.ableton.com/en/manual/routing-and-i-o/#routing-and-io); and

[Stylus RMX Reference Guide - Multi Patches](https://support.spectrasonics.net/manual/StylusRMX/1.9/en/topic/multi-patches?q=timbral).

12/31 Update: I just watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j0r_1xHKL4I) great youtube tutorial (the tutorial is for a different Spectrasonics product you've probably heard of--Omnisphere--but the routing options seem to be identical). I was able to follow along and replicate the author's setup in my own session; that being said, I am still left with some conceptual questions.

Please see minute 4:24--why does he need to select "OUT A", "OUT B", "OUT C" etc. when each channel already has, well, it's own channel? Further, in Ableton, when setting up the audio passthrough channels around minute 6:27, why does Ableton display "3/4", "5/6", "7/8" and so on until "17/18"?  I know these pairs of numbers relate to stereo channels, but I have no idea how that relates to what we're trying to do.

Additionally, at minute 8:05, he chooses "Sends Only" as the 'Audio To' for the host track.  I'm having trouble understanding the relationship between the host track and the first MIDI track (in his case titled "Omni 1").  I think his dealing with the outputs within Omnisphere at minute 4:00 pertains to the same quirk.

As you can see in the following screenshots, my session is much more tidy:

[image: arrangement view in ableton (12.31.23 update]

[image: mixer view in Stylus RMX]